# C# Simple file uploader fails to output a stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, file-upload, webclient, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to implement file uploading, directly from IsolatedStorage, in my WP7 app. I'm basing on this excellent example http://gregdoesit.com/2009/10/file-upload-in-silverlight-a-simple-solution/

Code I use to begin the UploadChunk() call chain is:

```
public void uploadPackage(String packagePath)
    {
        string[] pathSplit = packagePath.Split('\\');
        _fileName = pathSplit[1];
        IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream packageFile = isf.OpenFile(packagePath,     System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        _bytesUploaded = 0;
        _bytesTotal = packageFile.Length;
        _data = packageFile;

        try
        {
            UploadFileChunk();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

And everything seems to work well untill wc_OpenWriteCompleted event occurs. It is implemented like so:

```
if (e.Error == null)
        {
            object[] objArr = e.UserState as object[];
            byte[] fileContent = objArr[0] as byte[];    // NullReferenceException
            int bytesRead = Convert.ToInt32(objArr[1]);
            Stream outputStream = e.Result;
            outputStream.Write(fileContent, 0, bytesRead);
            outputStream.Close();
        }
```

objArr, in the 3rd line fails to be assinged, while e.UserState has a non null value. This causes the NullReferenceException in line 4., objArr is null.

What may cause the problem? I'm really stuck with this one, I would really appreciate any of your help.

Comment: well, put a breakpoint to that line at the debugger, and simply look at the e.UserState's type. the `as` operator yields null if the object is not the target type, in your case, `object[]`. but as you've told us it's not null, it must be something else.

Comment: thats right, e.UserState debugged, and definitely not null.